# How to create a merge request review from the GitLab api?

Tags: gitlab, review, gitlab-api, merge-request

I'm trying to replicate the ability to add reviews to GitLab merge requests in my app and I don't see anything in the api documentation related to merge request reviews or merge request draft notes.

On the web version of GitLab, when I create a comment on a line of code in a commit and I select 'Start a review', I can see a POST to `http://<myInstance>/<myProject/-/merge_requests/<id>/drafts`. If I execute a GET on that, I can see my pending review comment (note) in the response.

Is there anyway to create / read / update / delete merge request reviews with the GitLab api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as of Gitlab 13.9, there is no support for this. The closest it gets for an API for Merge Request Reviews is this issue/feature request asking for an API to retrieve Review comments: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/12297

If you're a paid user, contacting support/sales is a good option since they tend to add features themselves when paid users request it, but tend to let the community add an Open Source contribution otherwise.